# Cannot rewrite some html content with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, ajax

I wanna rewrite my `HTML` content with `ajax`. A part can be rewritten, but not for others. This is my **`js`** :

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/ThePrpuz/public/mahasiswa/getDetail',
    data: {
        nim: nim
    },
    method: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        if ((data.gender) == 'Wanita') {
            $('#foto').attr('src', 'http://localhost/theprpuz/public/img/cewek.jpg');
            $('#foto').attr('alt', 'Cewek');

        } else {
            $('#foto').attr('src', 'http://localhost/theprpuz/public/img/cowok.jpg');
            $('#foto').attr('alt', 'Cowok');
        }
        $('#nama').html(data.nama);
        $('#nim').html(data.nim);
        $('#univ').html(data.univ);
        $('#fakultas').html(data.fakultas);
        $('#jurusan').html(data.jurusan);
        $('#penjurusan').html(data.penjurusan);
        $('#ttl').html(data.tempat.concat(', ', data.tanggal));
    }
});
```

The problem is, content with ** `ID: ttl`** can be rewritten. But did not for others. The result like **this** :

```
Nama :
Nim :
TTl : Somewhere, sometime
Univ : 
Fakultas :
Jurusan : 
Penjurusan :
```

Ih this case, I use **`console.log(data)`** to see that my `ajax` works or not. and in `console`, these are **shown** :

```
{
  "nama": "Muhammad Fachri Saragih",
  "tanggal": "2001-09-11",
  "tempat": "Sibolga",
  "gender": "Pria",
  "univ": "Sriwijaya",
  "fakultas": "Ilmu Komputer",
  "jurusan": "Sistem Komputer",
  "penjurusan": "Jaringan",
  "nim": "9011281924069"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, try to check the data type of the "data". I think it can't be accessed because the data type is still string, not JSON.
try to parse data to JSON.

```
$.ajax({
url: 'http://localhost/ThePrpuz/public/mahasiswa/getDetail',
data: {
    nim: nim
},
method: 'post',
dataType: 'json',
success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(typeof data);
    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
    if ((obj.gender) == 'Wanita') {
        $('#foto').attr('src', 'http://localhost/theprpuz/public/img/cewek.jpg');
        $('#foto').attr('alt', 'Cewek');

    } else {
        $('#foto').attr('src', 'http://localhost/theprpuz/public/img/cowok.jpg');
        $('#foto').attr('alt', 'Cowok');
    }
    $('#nama').html(obj.nama);
    $('#nim').html(obj.nim);
    $('#univ').html(obj.univ);
    $('#fakultas').html(obj.fakultas);
    $('#jurusan').html(obj.jurusan);
    $('#penjurusan').html(obj.penjurusan);
    $('#ttl').html(obj.tempat.concat(', ', obj.tanggal));
}
});
```

Comment: thanks broh. Thats right. The data is string, not JSON

Answer (score 1):

The method `concat()` is used to join two or more arrays, not strings!
Replace

```js
$('#ttl').html(data.tempat.concat(', ', data.tanggal));
```

with

```js
$('#ttl').html(data.tempat + ', ' + data.tanggal);
```